# How to do templating / xml reusing in android properly

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic, templating

Before you flag me as duplicate and start the downvotes rolling, please know I am doing everything I can here to get this working for almost 3 hours now. I have tried four different methods, I read about in the Docs and various forum topics.

I have `Button` I defined in standalone `xml` file that looks like this:

```
<!--button_template.xml-->
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/score_question_btn"
    android:onClick="viewScore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:padding="24dp" />
```

I want to use it to populate a view dynamically.

What I have tried so far:

- `context.findViewById(R.id.button_id);` This does not work, because the button is not child view of the current context root view and thus returns `null`
- `LayoutInflator` -> `inflate(R.layout.button_template.xml, rootView, false);` I can't use this, because I need to set different text and background color to specific buttons.
- Use custom of `style resource`, defining `margins`, but I could not find a way to set `Button style`
- `Button button = new Button(context)` Simply put I cannot get this to work. I create `Button`, I can set text and color easily, but then there is a matter of `margins`.

After half an hour attempts to put freaking `margin` on the `Button`, I came up with this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
         new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int dpMargin = 16;
float d = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int marginInPixels = (int) (dpMargin * d);
params.setMargins(marginInPixels, marginInPixels, marginInPixels, 0);
```

But I wouldn't know if it works, because this is consistently crashing my project. It executes once, crashes and then I am unable to start my project, because it cannot locate my `MainActivity class`. I also spend an hour tracking this down. The only fix I came up with was to copy my `src` folder to new project.

So on the question: Am I on the right track? If so what am I doing wrong? If not - How would an experienced android developer approach this templeting issue.

Comment: "because I need to set different text and background color to specific buttons" -- you can call Java methods on your `Button` instances to set this information.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to acheive... you say "I want to use it to populate a view dynamically.". I guess you are trying to create a button layout xml and reuse that button on other parts of the app / inside other layouts , some linearlayouts etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `extend` the button class..

Here is an example

MyReusableButton.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyReusableButton extends Button {

    //use this constructor for button creation from java code
    public MyReusableButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    //this is needed for XML inflation
    public MyReusableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    //set button style
    private void init() {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    //helper to set margins
    public void setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //use this to create a button in code
        MyReusableButton b = new MyReusableButton(this);
        b.setText("Hello, World");

        //use this to add margins to the button
        b.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        //add the button to the parent linear layout
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper)).addView(b);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- We can also define a button in XML -->
    <com.example.test.MyReusableButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result of this code is 2 buttons, one from XML and one created programmatically. The `init()` method gives us the style that we want on every button.

I also included a helper method to set the margins to save on code in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try now. Aren't those margins in plain pixels. If so, how would you make them dp?

Comment: No Problem, there is a conversion to dp but I don't know if off of the top of my head, I am sure it has been answered on SO somewhere